# Magento 2.2 configurable products always out of stock

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, catalog

Configurable products are always out of stock but the are not in the catalog.
All assigned simple items are in stock with 100pcs.

I've noticed that if re do the configuration and Apply single quantity to each SKUs then i can see the product is is showing in stock again?

any solution i've almost 2000 products like this

Comment: Have you did reindexing command?

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, reindexing command solve the issue, but why the indexing my the admin panel did not solve it?

Comment: In magento 2, you cannot  indexing from admin like  Magento 1.Only can schedule indexing